# Why do I get an error in unity Web GL build?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl, yandex

Why do I get an error right before the completion of the progress bar for my WEB GL application, I don’t get anything in the browser console, I also don’t get anything in Android LogKat, after the error everything continues to work further without problems, only warnings in the logs.

The YandexGames and Unity 2022.2.16 service is used (Unity 2021.3.25 was also used)

[image]

**Here are the only errors that are at startup (Report Only does not interfere, but I see the warning for the first time):**

[image]

Comment: There's a lot of chatter to various sites. You wrote it. What does it need that its not getting

Comment: @BugFinder, sorry, but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: It cant find loads of maps. Couldnt connect to an sdk. We cant tell what your code does as to what it hasnt got that it needed to work